# How to get autofill working in VBA?

Tags: vba, autofill

I'm trying to get the autofill option to work. For one situation I only need to copy the values in a cell. In the other the formulas (but I guess this works the same as copying a value?).

This selects the cell I want to copy all the way down to the last filled cell in column B

```
Range("A1048576").End (xlUp)
```

Just adding the filldown option does not work. Any combination of .Select or .Value doesn't work either.

When I'm trying to simplify it by using this code, the filldown option doesn't work either.

```
Range("A11").Select
Selection.Filldown
```

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: You've only got one cell.  Filldown needs a range of cells to fill - `Range("A1:A11").Filldown` will take the value in A1 and filldown to A11.

Answer (score 1):

It's always good if you can use the macro recorder for such tasks and then edit the result to remove the `Select` and `ActiveCell`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Makro1()

    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "123"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A11"), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```